# Generating a property that invokes a method behind the scenes

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

I am currently working on adding a new feature to an existing API.

I am defining a new attribute, so that whenever a type is marked with that specific attribute, I want to loop through some list.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public class TestClass 
{
    List<int> Numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    public void Sum()
    {
        int total = 0;

        foreach (int i in Numbers)
        {
            total += i;
        }
    }
}
```

The decompiled C# code for the `Sum()` method is

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void Sum()
    {
        int num = 0;
        List<int>.Enumerator enumerator = Numbers.GetEnumerator();
        try
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                int current = enumerator.Current;
                num += current;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ((IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and the decompiled IL code is

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void Sum () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 59 (0x3b)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32,
        [1] valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>,
        [2] int32
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: nop
    IL_0004: ldarg.0
    IL_0005: ldfld class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> TestClass::Numbers
    IL_000a: callvirt instance valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!0> class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
    IL_000f: stloc.1
    .try
    {
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_0010: br.s IL_0020
        // loop start (head: IL_0020)
            IL_0012: ldloca.s 1
            IL_0014: call instance !0 valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::get_Current()
            IL_0019: stloc.2
            IL_001a: nop
            IL_001b: ldloc.0
            IL_001c: ldloc.2
            IL_001d: add
            IL_001e: stloc.0
            IL_001f: nop

            IL_0020: ldloca.s 1
            IL_0022: call instance bool valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::MoveNext()
            IL_0027: brtrue.s IL_0012
        // end loop

        IL_0029: leave.s IL_003a
    } // end .try
    finally
    {
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_002b: ldloca.s 1
        IL_002d: constrained. valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>
        IL_0033: callvirt instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
        IL_0038: nop
        IL_0039: endfinally
    } // end handler

    IL_003a: ret
} // end of method TestClass::Sum
```

([The decompiled code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAFgNwFgBQWoGYEBMcAKgKYDOALgMIA2AhueXFgN5ZydwAyAllQB5eAO0oA+OADkArgFsARqQBOzALxxhpAO49+lIaIms4iADRwC53OeTmArHAC+GTFxauueBMjgBlOQAUAJQcXOwebpwilHCUAPaU9LRw6jAukVyhGQBmcUqk9ADGABZwAdFwvJXCUnKKKiERkeEZGfGJyWDqvOmtjllOWI5AA==) is generated using `SharpLab.io`.)

Of particular interest is the `IL_0014` instruction, which invokes `get_Current()`. The corresponding decompiled C# code simply invokes the `Current` property on an enumerator.

**How can I emit this instruction using MonoCecil?** It would not work by creating a `MethodReference` with the name `get_Current`, because the decompiled C# code would then be `get_Current()`, not `Current`.

Comment: So you just want to know how to access a property in mono.cecil?

Comment: @canton7 Yes, indeed.

Comment: The title is misleading then - you're not asking how to generate a property, you're asking how to access one

Comment: Can't you access the `PropertyDefinition`, then call its `GetMethod`?

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for the suggestion; I will give it a try and update this question if necessary.

Comment: @canton7 You are right; I can do that. However, now I am seeing the error message "Member 'T System.Collections.Generic.List\`1/Enumerator::get_Current()' is declared in another module and needs to be imported", even though I have added "moduleDefinition.ImportReference(getCurrentPropertyMethod);". What am I missing?